# Add custom field in Activity Section

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, c#, custom

I am integrating salesforce in my application and got struck at one point how can we create a custom field in Activity (Calendar event) using C#. Currently I am able to create the custom field in custom objects but need to create the custom fields in Activity. Please check the below code for how I am creating the fields in custom objects.

```
WSDLRef.ActivityHistory history = new WSDLRef.ActivityHistory();
CustomObject cObject = new CustomObject();
cObject.fullName = "Vistaa__c";
cObject.deploymentStatus = MataDataWSDL.DeploymentStatus.Deployed;
cObject.deploymentStatusSpecified = true;
cObject.description = "Created by metadata API";
cObject.enableActivities = true;
cObject.enableActivitiesSpecified = true;
cObject.label = "Vista Object";
cObject.pluralLabel = cObject.label + "s";
cObject.sharingModel = MataDataWSDL.SharingModel.ReadWrite;
cObject.sharingModelSpecified = true;            
CustomField cf = new CustomField();
cf.description = "Simple text field from API";
cf.fullName = "Lead." + cObject.fullName + "__c";
String fieldLabel = "";
cf.label = fieldLabel.Length == 0 ? "Sample Field" : "Sample Field";
cf.length = 50;
cf.type = FieldType.Text;
cObject.nameField = cf;
MetadataService mBinding = new MetadataService();
mBinding.SessionHeaderValue = new MataDataWSDL.SessionHeader();
mBinding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId;
AsyncResult asyncResult = mBinding.create(new Metadata[] { cObject })[0];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I understand your question you have posted the code that works (for a custom object); I suggest you post the code that does not work too (for Activity) and any error you get. (Incidentally it is relatively unusual to add fields from code like this and more normal to pre-create them and install them as part of a managed package.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Means let user to create the custom field from their end no need to create it from code. Is there any procedure to find the Installed packages (Managed packages) in Salesforce account.

Comment: A problem with the approach of creating the field on the fly is that the User will have to be running with very high privileges (defined by their profile/permission sets) which could pose a security risk. On the managed package, I meant you would create one with your custom fields and objects and code in it. I don't know of an API to check directly for managed packages but you could detect whether your own was there or not pretty quickly by error responses when it is missing.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can I check if the existing Custom field is there or not in activity section. Thanks in advance

Comment: The clean way to do that is through the describe APIs (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm with various ways to access) where you can ask for all the field names on an object. The direct way is to just try and read the field and handle the error that results. Think its probably time to stop this thread now - this site aims to stick to a straight Q & A format... Good luck.